# How to integrate :Integral of $\int 1/(x^2+x+1)$ with substitution?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

How can I evaluate this integral with substitution :

> $$I=\int \frac 1 {(x^2+x+1)}dx$$

Comment: Complete the square, and then put  $(x+\frac 12) = \frac{\sqrt 3}2\tan\theta$

Comment: When you gonna stop outsourcing your homework? Please read in the help center the FAQ's under the title "Asking"?  Too many very poor questions that are nothing more than copied and pasted from a text from an assigned problem, and posting it, without any thoughts or workings from you, can lead to a question ban.  Start early to be informed, and post better questions (you'll see how in the help center), or you'll regret not having done so earlier.

Comment: O, btw... deleted questions, closed questions count against you as well, since it seems you've had a share of such deletions.

Comment: @amWhy Maybe it sounds to you like a poor question but as a student in year 9 it's bit difficult. I really tried doing it on my own but needed some help.

Comment: Please, the user is not in 9th grade.  Regardless, the asker wouldn't be where s/he is if he/she were entirely clueless, so much so that they can't state what they've been covering in class, in there text, explaining what they've tried, or asking for hints?  That's all responsible actions of an asker: provide some semblance of context.

Comment: @amWhy as a non English speaker it's difficult to state everything I had to translate everything first to ask this question. In mathematical English is too hard to express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write $$x^2+x+1$$ as $$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$$ and Substitute $$t=x+\frac{1}{2}$$
it is $$\frac{3}{4}\left(\left(\frac{2t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1\right)$$
and then Substitute $$y=\frac{2t}{\sqrt{3}}$$
this here should be a possible result: $$2/3\,\sqrt {3}\arctan \left( 1/3\, \left( 2\,x+1 \right) \sqrt {3}
 \right)
+C$$

Comment: Yes I tried that. So I would have [1/t^2+1) and it would be arctan in the end but I'm not getting it with the substitution

Comment: one Moment please i will post you some steps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally got it :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Putting $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt3}(x+\dfrac12)=t$ you get your integral equal to $$\dfrac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\right)+Constant$$ because of $\int\dfrac{dt}{t^2+1}=\arctan t+C$

Comment: How did you get to your hint with 2/root(3)?